# wait for the service to be stopped and proceed further in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying a shell script where it needs to wait for the service to be stopped and if its stopped proceed further in script, else it is hung exit from the script.Could someone help me on this. PFB script which I am trying

```
for i in 13.127.xxx.xxx xx.xxx.xxx.xx
do
    echo '############# Stopping the '$i' Apache service ################'
    ssh $i echo 'ansible' | sudo -S /etc/init.d/apache2 stop || { echo 'my command failed' ; exit 1 ; } 
    wait
    echo 'service has been stopped'

    echo '############# Status of the '$i' Apache service ################'
    abc=0
    abc=`ps -ef | grep "apache" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`

    if [ $abc -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Boomi process on $i is stopped, proceeding further!!!"
    else
        echo "Exiting the script as Script could not stop the Boomi process, Please check the issue " ; exit 1;

    fi

    sleep 10
    ssh $i echo 'ansible' | sudo -S /etc/init.d/apache2 status
done
```

Comment: Hey! When checking abc, why are you checking locally and not in the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should warn, that passing unencrypted password using pipe redirection over a simple ssh bash command is unsafe and bad. One that could inspect the script would immediately gain root access to your nodes. The proper way is to add a line sudoers file for executing specified commands (/etc/init.d/apache and pgrep) as a normal, unprivileged user.

```
for i in 13.127.xxx.xxx xx.xxx.xxx.xx; do

    echo '############# Stopping the '"$i"' Apache service ################'
    if ! ssh "$i" 'echo ansible | sudo -S /etc/init.d/apache2 stop'; then
        echo "ERROR: stopping apache2 on $i failed!" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    echo 'service has been stopped'

    echo '############# Status of the '"$i"' Apache service ################'
    ssh "$i" 'echo ansible | sudo -S pgrep apache' && ret=$? || ret=$?
    if [ "$ret" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "apache process is not stopped"
    elif [ "$ret" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "apache process was successfully stopped"
    else
        echo "error in executing ssh + pgrep"
        exit 1
    fi

    sleep 10
    ssh "$i" 'echo ansible | sudo -S /etc/init.d/apache2 status'
done
```

You forgot about the quotes. If you run `ssh $i echo ansible | ....` the part in `...` get's executed locally, not on the remote machine. The `|` character separates commands, just like `;` or `&&` or `||` or `&`. Except for separating the commands, it also joins the first command stdout to the others stdin.

To run everything on the other host, you need to pass it as an argument to ssh `ssh $i "echo ansible | ...."`. The whole command is passed to ssh, the remote shell then splits the command again into tokens, and executes the `echo ansible` and `...` part as two commands separated with `|`.

Answer (score 0):

To me the script should looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 13.127.xxx.xxx xx.xxx.xxx.xx
do
    echo '############# Stopping the '$i' Apache service ################'
    ssh $i echo "ansible | sudo -S /etc/init.d/apache2 stop" || { echo 'my command failed' ; exit 1 ; }
    wait
    echo 'service has been stopped'

    echo '############# Status of the '$i' Apache service ################'
    abc=0
    abc=$(ssh $i echo "ansible | sudo -S pgrep apache | wc -l")

    if [ "$abc" -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Boomi process on $i is stopped, proceeding further!!!"
    else
        echo "Exiting the script as Script could not stop the Boomi process, Please check the issue " ; exit 1;

    fi

    sleep 10
    ssh $i echo "ansible | sudo -S /etc/init.d/apache2 status"
done
```

Check quotes and abc var when ssh'ing your hosts